# What kind of filter do I need if I want to reuse the shower water?

Tags: water, gardening, water-filtration

I am helping a friend with renewing a bathroom. He is looking at the possibility of storing and reusing the shower water for the garden.

What kind of filter do we need to install to make this possible? I suppose we need to remove the soap and any other particles.
Is it even feasible in a simple way?

Comment: Research grey water

Comment: Yes, it probably isn't even legal if you're in a city.

Comment: You wouldn't normally try to remove soap, etc from grey water before it's used for garden watering.

Comment: You would not use any filter. Dilute soap is not harmful to a garden.  I would expect that the problem would be harsh cleaners like chlorine bleach. Probably most of these greywater-to-garden plumbing  arrangements would have valves to direct harmful cleaning compounds to the sanitary sewer.

Comment: @JimStewart but even shampoos and so are fine? I will probably get a soap on the bottom of  the deposit, not?

Comment: The ingredients in shampoos are approved for human skin and incidentally getting into the eyes; they are not toxic to the garden.

Comment: They make soaps and shampoos which are more friendly to this.

Answer (score 1):

Step one is up to the local jurisdiction having authority - is this even legal in the specific place you want to do it? If not, fugeddaboutit.

After that there are many options - a reed bed filter is common in "permaculture" applications, a sand filter is another approach.